# arcpy SelectByAttribute_management

Tags: arcpy, select-by-attribute

I try to add a point xy to feature class and I want to select the latest record in table (recently added). The script runs and I don't have any error message but the tool doesn't select any thing. How can I fix this?

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = r'D:\Geodatabases\BD_VOCATION.gdb '
points = r'D:\Geodatabases\BD_VOCATION.gdb\Loc_vocation'
try:
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(points,'points_layer')    
    rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(points,'','',"OBJECTID", "OBJECTID D")    
    lst = []    
    for row in rows:    
        m = row.getValue("OBJECTID")    
        lst.append(m)    
    v = lst[0]    
    r= str(v)     
    query = """{0} = {1}""".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(points, "OBJECTID"), int(r))        
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("points_layer", "NEW_SELECTION", query)
except:    
    print "An error occured during selection"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [da.SearchCursor](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/searchcursor-class.htm) instead of the old cursor, they are much faster. You are adding field delimiters for `points` when it should be `'points_lyr`'`. And when using try/except you make debugging difficult since the errors are hidden.

Try:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\GIS\ArcMap_default_folder\Default.gdb'
points = 'cpoints'

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(points,'points_layer')
oidfield = arcpy.Describe('points_layer').OIDFieldName

#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138873/cleanest-way-to-get-last-item-from-python-iterator
for item in arcpy.da.SearchCursor('points_layer',oidfield):
    pass

sql = """{0}={1}""".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters('points_layer', oidfield), item[0])
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("points_layer", "NEW_SELECTION", sql)
```

[image]

Comment: Might be better using a list comprehension with `max()`, since the greatest  fid value isn't *required* to be the last returned (unless and `ORDER BY` is provided, then you could slice it)

Comment: Thank you very match I'm just a beginner in arcpy. I would appreciate your help in finding a solution. but just one last thing the script runs pretty well in python console in Arcmap but it fails in Pyscripter!!! any help please

Comment: What do you mean by fails

Comment: I mean it doesn't select anything

Comment: How can you tell? `print arcpy.GetCount_management("points_layer")[0]`

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean but it returns 1

Comment: Then it is probably working, one row is selected.

Comment: So why it didn't select anything in ArcMap!

Comment: Because you run the code in an external IDE. That is the expected behavior.

Comment: But i create a tool in the toolbox in ArcMap and I get the same result

Comment: Now your problem is completely different from your original question.

Comment: I'm satisfied, thank you very much for your precious help :)

Comment: Nice. The way to say thank you here is to accept answer with the checkbox and upvote